# Perform Calculation on Every Row, Except The First - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have three columns: `year`, `return`, `growth_of_1k`. What I'd like to so is calculate the growth of $1,000 using the `return` column, and save it to `growth_of_1k`.

To visualize, here's what my dataframe currently looks like:

| year | return | growth_of_1k |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | 0.1 | 1000 |
| 2011 | 0.4 | NaN |
| 2012 | 0.3 | NaN |

What I'd like to do is take the previous year's `growth_of_1k` and multiply it by this year's `return`.

Right now I have this:

```
df['growth_of_1k'] = df['growth_of_1k'].shift(1) * (1 + df['return'])
```

However, the code above only updates the second row, and nothing else. Any idea on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try `cumprod`:

```
df['return'].where(np.arange(len(df))>0, 0).add(1).cumprod() * df.loc[0, 'growth_of_1k']
```

output:

```
0    1000.0
1    1400.0
2    1820.0
Name: return, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```py
df.loc[df.index[1:], 'growth_of_1k'] = (df.loc[df.index[1:], 'return'] + 1).cumprod() * df.growth_of_1k.iat[0]
```

Output:

```
   year  return  growth_of_1k
0  2010     0.1        1000.0
1  2011     0.4        1400.0
2  2012     0.3        1820.0
```